# Почему выполнение приложения резко замедляется в Ubuntu без видимых на то причин?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Прошу вас взглянуть на [код](https://github.com/NicholasShatokhin/OpenNNL), а именно на функции `_changeWeightsByBP` и `_changeWeightsByIDBD` в файле opennnl.cpp. Вторая функция имеет дополнительные вычисления и нуждается в большем количестве памяти. Она медленнее первой, но по идее не на слишком. При этом когда я запускаю обучении нейронной сети на 60000 примеров с использованием второй, процесс резко замедляется после обработки примерно 2700 примеров, хотя первая работает одинаково быстро на всем множестве. Подозреваю, что это Убунта каким-то образом замедляет приложение. Почему такое может происходить и как с этим бороться?

Итак, я запустил профайлер. Но не могу понять его вывод. Кто-нибудь может мне подсказать, что замедляет?

```
robotex@robotex-laptop:~/workspace/OpenNNL$ pprof --text ./OpenNNL opennnl.prof  
Using local file ./OpenNNL.
Using local file opennnl.prof.
Removing _init from all stack traces.
Total: 17482 samples
    5460  31.2%  31.2%     7231  41.4% OpenNNL::_changeWeightsByIDBD
    4661  26.7%  57.9%     4661  26.7% 008c7880
    1645   9.4%  67.3%     1645   9.4% OpenNNL::calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives
    1631   9.3%  76.6%     1631   9.3% 008c7886
    1348   7.7%  84.3%     1348   7.7% 008c787a
     790   4.5%  88.9%      790   4.5% 008caf23
     234   1.3%  90.2%      234   1.3% 008c787c
     218   1.2%  91.4%      218   1.2% 008c7884
     147   0.8%  92.3%      147   0.8% __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx@4747 (inline)
     144   0.8%  93.1%      144   0.8% 008c7866
     137   0.8%  93.9%      137   0.8% 008c7860
     122   0.7%  94.6%      122   0.7% __munmap
     120   0.7%  95.3%      120   0.7% _init
     117   0.7%  96.0%      117   0.7% 008c786d
      73   0.4%  96.4%       73   0.4% 008caef6
      73   0.4%  96.8%       73   0.4% 008caf03
      66   0.4%  97.2%       66   0.4% 008caf0b
      61   0.3%  97.5%       61   0.3% 008caef0
      60   0.3%  97.9%       60   0.3% 008c7872
      57   0.3%  98.2%       57   0.3% 008c787e
      53   0.3%  98.5%       53   0.3% 008c7869
      52   0.3%  98.8%       52   0.3% 008c7878
      52   0.3%  99.1%       52   0.3% 008caf17
      51   0.3%  99.4%       51   0.3% 008c7876
      21   0.1%  99.5%       21   0.1% 008c7867
      13   0.1%  99.6%       13   0.1% 008caf1b
      12   0.1%  99.6%       12   0.1% 008caf11
      12   0.1%  99.7%    17453  99.8% testNetwork2
       8   0.0%  99.7%        8   0.0% OpenNNL::randomizeWeights
       8   0.0%  99.8%        8   0.0% __mmap
       7   0.0%  99.8%        7   0.0% __write_nocancel
       5   0.0%  99.9%        5   0.0% sYSMALLOc
       4   0.0%  99.9%        4   0.0% __memcpy_ssse3
       3   0.0%  99.9%        3   0.0% _int_free
       2   0.0%  99.9%        2   0.0% 008caef1
       2   0.0%  99.9%        2   0.0% __GI___libc_malloc
       1   0.0%  99.9%        1   0.0% 008c7882
       1   0.0%  99.9%        1   0.0% 008caf19
       1   0.0%  99.9%        1   0.0% 008caf1e
       1   0.0%  99.9%        1   0.0% 008caf26
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% OpenNNL::randomizeBs
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% OpenNNL::resetHsAndHsForBias
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% _IO_fwrite
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% __GI___libc_free
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx@126c73
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% _int_malloc
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% operator new
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% rand
       1   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.0% std::basic_ostream::sentry::sentry
       0   0.0% 100.0%    17426  99.7% OpenNNL::_doEpochIDBD
       0   0.0% 100.0%    17429  99.7% OpenNNL::_trainingIDBD
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.0% OpenNNL::randomizeBsAndBsForBias
       0   0.0% 100.0%        8   0.0% OpenNNL::randomizeWeightsAndBiases
       0   0.0% 100.0%    17433  99.7% OpenNNL::trainingIDBD
       0   0.0% 100.0%      147   0.8% __GI___exp (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0%      147   0.8% __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx@4747
       0   0.0% 100.0%    17453  99.8% __libc_start_main
       0   0.0% 100.0%    17453  99.8% main
```

**UPD.:** Привожу основные куски кода:

```
double OpenNNL::_changeWeightsByBP(double * trainingInputs, double *trainingOutputs, double speed, double sample_weight)
{
    double error = 0, current_error;
    double * localGradients = new double[_neuronsCount];
    double * outputs = new double[_neuronsCount];
    double * derivatives = new double[_neuronsCount];

    calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives(trainingInputs, outputs, derivatives);

    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[_layersCount-1];j++) // cuda kernel
    {
        current_error = trainingOutputs[j] - outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)];
        localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)] = current_error * sample_weight * derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)];

        error += current_error * current_error;
    }

    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++) // cuda kernel
            {
                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] = 0;

                for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1];k++)
                {
                    localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] += _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i+1, k, j)]
                                                                    * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i+1, k)];
                }

                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] *= derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[0];j++) // this and next cicle for cuda kernel (j*k threads)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<_inputsCount;k++)
        {
            _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(0, j, k)] += speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * trainingInputs[k];
        }

        _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] -= speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)];
    }

    for(int i=1;i<_layersCount;i++) // try to parallelize all three cicles in one kernel. If it's impossible, only two inner
    {
        for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i-1];k++)
            {
                _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i, j, k)] += speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)];
            }

            _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] -= speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];
        }
    }

    delete[] localGradients;
    delete[] outputs;
    delete[] derivatives;

    error /= 2;
    return error;
}

double OpenNNL::_changeWeightsByIDBD(double * trainingInputs, double *trainingOutputs, double speed, double sample_weight)
{
    double error = 0, current_error;
    double cur_rate, delta, deltaB, deltaH;
    double * localGradients = new double[_neuronsCount];
    double * outputs = new double[_neuronsCount];
    double * derivatives = new double[_neuronsCount];

    calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives(trainingInputs, outputs, derivatives);

    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[_layersCount-1];j++)
    {
        current_error = trainingOutputs[j] - outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)];
        localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)] = current_error * sample_weight * derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(_layersCount-1, j)];

        error += current_error * current_error;
    }

    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
            {
                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] = 0;

                for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1];k++)
                {
                    localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] += _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i+1, k, j)]
                                                                    * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i+1, k)];
                }

                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] *= derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[0];j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<_inputsCount;k++)
        {
            deltaB = speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * trainingInputs[k] * getH(0, j, k);

            if (deltaB > 2.0)
            {
                deltaB = 2.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (deltaB < -2.0)
                {
                    deltaB = -2.0;
                }
            }

            setB(0, j, k, getB(0, j, k) + deltaB);
            cur_rate = exp(getB(0, j, k));
            delta = cur_rate * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * trainingInputs[k];

            _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(0, j, k)] += delta;

            deltaH = 1 - cur_rate * trainingInputs[k] * trainingInputs[k];
            if(deltaH <= 0)
                setH(0, j, k, delta);
            else
                setH(0, j, k, getH(0, j, k) * deltaH + delta);
        }

        deltaB = speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * getHForBias(0, j);

        if (deltaB > 2.0)
        {
            deltaB = 2.0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (deltaB < -2.0)
            {
                deltaB = -2.0;
            }
        }

        setBForBias(0, j, getBForBias(0, j) - deltaB);
        cur_rate = exp(getBForBias(0, j));
        delta = cur_rate * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)];

        _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] -= delta;

        deltaH = 1 - cur_rate;
        if(deltaH <= 0)
            setHForBias(0, j, -delta);
        else
            setHForBias(0, j, getHForBias(0, j) * deltaH - delta);
    }

    for(int i=1;i<_layersCount;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i-1];k++)
            {
                deltaB = speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)] * getH(i, j, k);

                if (deltaB > 2.0)
                {
                    deltaB = 2.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (deltaB < -2.0)
                    {
                        deltaB = -2.0;
                    }
                }

                setB(i, j, k, getB(i, j, k) + deltaB);
                cur_rate = exp(getB(i, j, k));
                delta = cur_rate * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)];

                _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i, j, k)] += delta;

                deltaH = 1 - cur_rate * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)] * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)];
                if(deltaH <= 0)
                    setH(i, j, k, delta);
                else
                    setH(i, j, k, getH(i, j, k) * deltaH + delta);
            }

            deltaB = speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] * getHForBias(i, j);

            if (deltaB > 2.0)
            {
                deltaB = 2.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (deltaB < -2.0)
                {
                    deltaB = -2.0;
                }
            }

            setBForBias(i, j, getBForBias(i, j) - deltaB);
            cur_rate = exp(getBForBias(i, j));
            delta = cur_rate * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];

            _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] -= delta;

            deltaH = 1 - cur_rate;
            if(deltaH <= 0)
                setHForBias(i, j, -delta);
            else
                setHForBias(i, j, getHForBias(i, j) * deltaH - delta);
        }
    }

    delete[] localGradients;
    delete[] outputs;
    delete[] derivatives;

    error /= 2;
    return error;
}

bool OpenNNL::_doEpochBP(int samplesCount, double * trainingInputs, double * trainingOutputs, int numEpoch, double speed, double minError)
{
    double error = 0;
    double * currentSampleInputs = new double[_inputsCount];
    double * currentSampleOutputs = new double[_outputsCount];

    for(int sample=0;sample<samplesCount;sample++)
    {
        cout << "Epoch: " << numEpoch << ", Sample: " << sample << endl;
        memcpy(currentSampleInputs, trainingInputs+sample*_inputsCount, _inputsCount*sizeof(double));
        memcpy(currentSampleOutputs, trainingOutputs+sample*_outputsCount, _outputsCount*sizeof(double));

        error = _changeWeightsByBP(currentSampleInputs, currentSampleOutputs, speed, 1);
    }

    delete[] currentSampleInputs;
    delete[] currentSampleOutputs;

    return (error <= minError);
}

bool OpenNNL::_doEpochIDBD(int samplesCount, double * trainingInputs, double * trainingOutputs, int numEpoch, double speed, double minError)
{
    double error = 0;
    double * currentSampleInputs = new double[_inputsCount];
    double * currentSampleOutputs = new double[_outputsCount];

    for(int sample=0;sample<samplesCount;sample++)
    {
        cout << "Sample: " << sample << endl;
        memcpy(currentSampleInputs, trainingInputs+sample*_inputsCount, _inputsCount*sizeof(double));
        memcpy(currentSampleOutputs, trainingOutputs+sample*_outputsCount, _outputsCount*sizeof(double));

        error = _changeWeightsByIDBD(currentSampleInputs, currentSampleOutputs, speed, 1);
    }

    delete[] currentSampleInputs;
    delete[] currentSampleOutputs;

    return (error <= minError);
}

void OpenNNL::_trainingBP(int samplesCount, double * trainingInputs, double * trainingOutputs, int maxEpochsCount, double speed, double error)
{
    for(int i=0;i<maxEpochsCount;i++)
    {
        if(_doEpochBP(samplesCount, trainingInputs, trainingOutputs, i, speed, error))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void OpenNNL::_trainingIDBD(int samplesCount, double * trainingInputs, double * trainingOutputs, int maxEpochsCount, double speed, double error)
{
    for(int i=0;i<maxEpochsCount;i++)
    {
        if(_doEpochIDBD(samplesCount, trainingInputs, trainingOutputs, i, speed, error))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void OpenNNL::trainingBP(int samplesCount, double * trainingInputs, double *trainingOutputs, int maxEpochsCount, double speed, double error)
{
    _trainingBP(samplesCount, trainingInputs, trainingOutputs, maxEpochsCount, speed, error);
}

void OpenNNL::trainingIDBD(int samplesCount, double * trainingInputs, double *trainingOutputs, int maxEpochsCount, double speed, double error)
{
    _Bs = new double[_weightsCount];
    _Hs = new double[_weightsCount];

    _BsForBias = new double[_neuronsCount];
    _HsForBias = new double[_neuronsCount];

    resetHsAndHsForBias();
    randomizeBsAndBsForBias();

    _trainingIDBD(samplesCount, trainingInputs, trainingOutputs, maxEpochsCount, speed, error);

    delete[] _Bs;
    delete[] _Hs;
    delete[] _BsForBias;
    delete[] _HsForBias;
}

inline int OpenNNL::indexByLayerAndNeuron(int layer, int neuron)
{
    return _neuronsInPreviousLayers[layer] + neuron;
}

inline int OpenNNL::indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(int layer, int neuron, int input)
{
    return _inputsInPreviousLayers[layer] + neuron*_inputsInCurrentLayer[layer] + input;
}

inline void OpenNNL::setB(int layer, int neuron, int input, double value)
{
    _Bs[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(layer, neuron, input)] = value;
}

inline double OpenNNL::getB(int layer, int neuron, int input)
{
    return _Bs[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(layer, neuron, input)];
}

inline void OpenNNL::setBForBias(int layer, int neuron, double value)
{
    _BsForBias[indexByLayerAndNeuron(layer, neuron)] = value;
}

inline double OpenNNL::getBForBias(int layer, int neuron)
{
    return _BsForBias[indexByLayerAndNeuron(layer, neuron)];
}

inline void OpenNNL::setH(int layer, int neuron, int input, double value)
{
    _Hs[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(layer, neuron, input)] = value;
}

inline double OpenNNL::getH(int layer, int neuron, int input)
{
    return _Hs[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(layer, neuron, input)];
}

inline void OpenNNL::setHForBias(int layer, int neuron, double value)
{
    _HsForBias[indexByLayerAndNeuron(layer, neuron)] = value;
}

inline double OpenNNL::getHForBias(int layer, int neuron)
{
    return _HsForBias[indexByLayerAndNeuron(layer, neuron)];
}

inline void OpenNNL::setWeight(int layer, int neuron, int input, double value)
{
    _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(layer, neuron, input)] = value;
}

inline double OpenNNL::getWeight(int layer, int neuron, int input)
{
    return _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(layer, neuron, input)];
}

inline void OpenNNL::setBias(int layer, int neuron, double value)
{
    _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(layer, neuron)] = value;
}

inline double OpenNNL::getBias(int layer, int neuron)
{
    return _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(layer, neuron)];
}
```

**UPD.:** Мой процессор

```
robotex@robotex-laptop:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7500  @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 11
microcode   : 0xb3
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips    : 4388.96
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7500  @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 11
microcode   : 0xb3
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips    : 4388.98
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), предлагаю поговорить по мылу n.shatokhin@gmail.com, а то вопрос уже слишком раздулся. А когда решим проблему, то просто разместите тут ответ, а я признаю его лучшим.

Comment: может просто она кушает памяти больше, чем есть доступной оперативной? в таком случае она начнет свопиться и будет конкретное замедление. А убунта тут не причем.

Comment: Памяти то она кушает больше, но вот только вся память выделяется перед началом вычислений. И количество занятой памяти никогда не превышает 40% (с учетом всех процессов в системе), а индикатор свопа всегда пуст. Выходит не в памяти дело.

Comment: Видимо разница в алгоритмах. Например, в первом используется сортировка со временем O(N\*Log N), а во втором O(N^2).

Comment: Вот больше нечего делать Убунте, кроме как замедлять ваше приложение =)

Comment: Если я объединю несколько массивов в один, это может помочь защититься от переполнения кеша? Или критичен именно размер, а не количество?

Вообще, какие факторы обычно вызывают проблемы с кешем?

Comment: @Robotex, объединение не поможет, критичен именно суммарный объем данных.

Почитайте, например, [здесь](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/008/008r.shtml).

Особо обратите внимание на *опережающую* выборку из памяти.


Детали, конечно, меняются, но общие принципы остаются (скорость чтения из кэша и памяти может отличаться на 2 порядка).

--

Очевидно, что в своей задаче Вы должны стремиться к алгоритму, который **максимизирует** вычисления для групп даннных целиком помещающихся в кэш.

Обсчитали во вложенных циклах что можно для части данных, сменили их (наверное не все), посчитали для новых и т.д.

Comment: А можно где-то посмотреть пример кода, реализующий такое разбиение? Да еще и с учетом размера кеша (процессоры ведь разные и кеши разные, как это учесть?)
Ведь как-то же делают софт, работающий с гигантскими массивами данных. Как они избегают этой проблемы?

Comment: @Robotex, замечательный вопрос. Вы его как-то **отдельно оформите и выносите на обсуждение**.

Конкретно о коде - где посмотреть - я не знаю. Размер кэша проще всего вытащить из /proc/cpuinfo.

В Вашем случае типичная величина _neuronsPerLayerCount[i] видимо большая (кстати, какая именно?), поэтому (в 3-х `for` по `i,j,k`) для каждого нового `i` в кэше уже нет данных для j==0. Я это так понимаю.

Да, места тут мало (я помню Ваше предложение о e-mail, но поймите, я не специалист по нейронным сетям, если будут конкретные вопросы пишите на avp210159@gmail.com, но плотно заниматься не обещаю).

Answer (score 4):

Выскажу лишь догадки, т.к. чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос более достоверно, нужно хоть как-то профилировать работающую программу.

1. Функция `_changeWeightsByIDBD` по определению работает с б*о*льшим объемом данных, нежели `_changeWeightsByBP`. Это приводит к тому, что при интенсивной работе с несколькими массивами данных, не влезающими в процессорный кэш, этот самый кэш постоянно перегружается и CPU приходится простаивать в ожидании поступления данных. На больших массивах это может быть очень заметно.
2. Вызов функции `setBForBias`, которого нет в `_changeWeightsByBP`. Это также может приводить к переключению текущего контекста, а значит и перегрузке кэша, т.к. функция обращается к другим массивам.
3. Не оптимально выполнена работа с элементами массивов. Например, в одном и том же цикле часто фигурирует конструкция вида `localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)]`, которую приходится многократно повторно вычислять. Можно использовать *ссылку* на элемент контейнера `localGradients` и в одной итерации работать с ней:

   int & local_gradient = localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)]

Ну а вообще стоит всерьез озаботиться проблемой профилирования вашего кода, чтобы не тратить время на оптимизацию того, что не нужно оптимизировать.

**UPD:**

Выдержка из [документации по google-perftools](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html):

> Text mode has lines of output that
> look like this:
>
> ```
>    14   2.1%  17.2%       58   8.7% std::_Rb_tree::find Here is how to interpret the columns:
> ```
>
> 1. Number of profiling samples in this function
> 2. Percentage of profiling samples in this function
> 3. Percentage of profiling samples in the functions printed so far
> 4. Number of profiling samples in this function and its callees
> 5. Percentage of profiling samples in this function and its callees
> 6. Function name

Собственно, hotspot вам уже представлен - `_changeWeightsByIDBD()`, - он находится вверху таблицы результатов профилирования. Теперь необходимо понять, что именно в этой функции вносит наибольший вклад.

Сперва обратим внимание на 1й и 4й показатели в hotspot - их разница составляет примерно 1800 ед. (сымплов), а значит, что большая часть времени ( уходит непосредственно на работу внутри тела функции, а не в вызванных ею методах. В подтверждение этому в третье строке приведены показатели для функции `calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives()`, вызываемой все из той же `_changeWeightsByIDBD()`. Кол-во ее сымплов 1645, что как раз укладывается в те 1800, которые мы рассчитали выше.

Отсюда следует вывод, что из общего времени выполнения `_changeWeightsByIDBD()` примерно четверть занимает `calculateNeuronsOutputsAndDerivatives()`, а остальное - работа именно самой функции.

Еще предлагаю построить call-graph, может он поможет пролить ясность на загадочные адреса функций, для которых небыло символов. Скорее всего, это различные системные функции, и интересно, кто они и кто их вызывает.

Дальше можно пойти по двум путям: или методом проб и ошибок выяснять, что в функции наиболее "трудоемко" и что является узким местом; или (что рекомендуется) проводить более детальное профилирование именно этой функции - сделать анализ аппаратных событий (hardware events) - память, шину, кэш процессора.

**UPD:**

Как правильно указал уважаемый [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), медленная функция обращается к ряду доп. массивов. Вот размер массивов для 60000 нейронов, как вы указали в вопросе:

```
_BsForBias = new double[_neuronsCount];
_HsForBias = new double[_neuronsCount];
```

Итого получается `2х60000х8 = 960000` байт, т.е. почти 1MB непрерывной области памяти уйдет на эти два массива. А ведь там еще много разных данных...

*Основная идея оптимизации в таком случае заключается в том, чтобы свести к минимуму необходимость перезагружать содержимое кэша.*

Пример. Если уменьшить размер массивов не удается алгоритмическим путем, то остается изменить алгоритм работы `_changeWeightsByIDBD` так, чтобы работа с указанными большими массивами была как можно более локализована: идеально было бы, если удастся организовать последовательную работу с ними - сперва обрабатываем массив `_BsForBias`, затем `_HsForBias`. Еще вариант: обрабатывать оба массива "порционно", так, чтобы суммарный размер обеих "порций" гарантированно влезал в кэш.

Comment: Чем можно профилировать код в Ubunt'е?

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум, это grof: http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gprof/

Comment: gprof не айс совсем. Мне нравится google-perftools http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1.

Comment: @dzhioev, на gprof настаивать не буду, поскольку я сам реально профилирую только под Win с помощью Inter VTune Amplifier.

Comment: обновил вопрос, приложил туда вывод профайлера

Comment: Но в _changeWeightsByBP() тоже эта функция вызывается, но при этом приложение работает с нормальной скоростью

Comment: Здесь очень большое значение играет контекст, а именно то, с каким объемом памяти работает функция `_changeWeightsByIDBD`. Советую провести memory exploration test на основе именно *аппаратных событий*, а не сэмплирования. Это позволит понять, в чем именно у этой функции проблемы.

Comment: Как это делается?

Comment: К сожалению, как это делается при профилировании в Linux, я вам сказать не смогу, т.к. сам профилирую в Win с помощью VTune. Могу предложить поискать в Google - наверняка вы не первый, кто сталкивается с подобной задачей.

Comment: Не думаю, что надо опускаться на уровень аппаратуры. 

@Robotex, Вы бы основные куски кода и данных выдрали из гита (ну, не качать же нам все и т.д.) и привели здесь. Тогда можно предметно обсудить.

Скорее всего проблема с тем, что какие-то массивы не помещаются в кэш.

Answer (score 2):

[@Robotex](/users/8635/robotex), обратите внимание на **существенное** различие в функциях _changeWeightsByBP и _changeWeightsByIDBD.
В более быстрой _changeWeightsByBP обратите **особое внимание** на слова *cuda* и *try to parallelize* в комментариях

```
for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[0];j++) // this and next cicle for cuda kernel (j*k threads)
{
    for(int k=0;k<_inputsCount;k++)
    {
        _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(0, j, k)] += speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * trainingInputs[k];
    }

    _neuronsBiases[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] -= speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)];
}

for(int i=1;i<_layersCount;i++) // try to parallelize all three cicles in one kernel. If it's impossible, only two inner
{
    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
    {
       .......
```

Эта же часть в  _changeWeightsByIDBD выглядит по другому

```
for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[0];j++)
{
    for(int k=0;k<_inputsCount;k++)
    {
        deltaB = speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(0, j)] * trainingInputs[k] * getH(0, j, k);
        if (deltaB > 2.0)
        {
            deltaB = 2.0;
            ..........
```

и дальше

```
for(int i=1;i<_layersCount;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++)
    {
    .......
```

Как в _changeWeightsByBP задействуется cuda (параллельные вычисления на GPU) не знаю. Думаю все дело в этом.

Comment: слова cuda и try to parallelize в комментариях я добавил для себя, чтобы не забыть, что именно надо будет распараллелить в будущем в версии для cuda. Не обращайте на это внимания, тут нету куды.

Comment: Отличие функции IDBD от BP в том, что там добавлены вычисления массивов B и H, необходимых для вычисления коэффициента скорости обучения (единственное отличие алгоритма IDBD от BP).

Comment: @Robotex, ну нет куды и не надо. Простой вопрос - сколько времени (порядок - секунды, миллисекунды) выполняется один вызов этих функций?

Это я к тому, получится ли что-то разумное померять внутри, вставляя код с gettimeofday(). 

Для начала интересно померить время выполнения внешних циклов (не залезая пока внутрь), пемеченных комментариями в одной функции и аналогичных им в другой, и время исполнения всей функции.

Вы можете это проделать? Также интересно количество выполнений внешнего и внутренних циклов. 

И размер кэша Вашей машины. (cat /proc/cpuinfo)

Comment: Кэш CPU 4MB увидел.

Вот посмотрел я на код еще раз. В "быстрой" функции самый вложенный цикл

    for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i-1];k++)
            {
                _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i, j, k)] += speed * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] * outputs[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i-1, k)];
            }

затрагивет 3 массива (_neuronsInputsWeights[], localGradients[], outputs[] ).  В "медленной"  к ним добавляется _HS[], _HsForBias[], _Bs[] и  _BsForBias[].

Хотелось бы узнать их размеры. IMHO в этом и проблема.

(места мало, но думаю идея понятна - кэш

Comment: И как с этим быть? Как бороться?

Массивы _HS[] и _Bs[] равны по размеру массиву _neuronsInputsWeights, а _HsForBias[] и _BsForBias[] массиву localGradients

Comment: @Robotex, Вы так и не привели конкретных цифр (замеров размеров массивов в элементах/байтах и времени выполнения циклов) для  IDBD и BP в момент, когда IDBD становится слишком медленной. Поэтому мои рассуждения о кэше остаются только предположениями.

--

Как с этим бороться? 

Хороший вопрос.

Видимо надо так изменить структуры данных (например перегруппировать данные в массивах (иногда это возможно, иногда нет)), чтобы работа с памятью в самом внутреннем цикле приходилась на несколько не очень больших диапазонов адресов.

При этом возможно придется заменить один внутренний цикл на несколько

Comment: Ну это не решение. Если размеры нейронной сети увеличатся, то оно опять начнет замедляться. Как бы так реализовать, чтобы оно разбивалось на пакеты независимо от размера сети.

Замеры сделаю на днях. Предположение предположением, но в любом случае на определенных размерах сети, данные перестанут помещаться в кеш, а значит надо что-то с этим делать.

Comment: @Robotex, очевидно для этого надо глубоко разбираться в алгоритме (и предметной области). Чисто формальный подход к размещению данных в памяти скорее всего ни к чему хорошему не приведет.

--

Кстати, у нас с Вами лимит комментариев в теме (в этом ответе) заканчивается. Видимо дальше (вот ведь дурь!) придется делать **Upd** (мне к ответу, а Вам к вопросу (а он очень длинный)).

Answer (score 0):

Забейте на все, отдайте все ресурсы машины процессу с помощью программы nice;)